# python supervised learning with data set classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, pattern-matching

I am new to deep learning and am currently researching a certain topic. I am looking for machine learning detection of anomalies in time series pattern and their implementation in python.

For example, I have a recording of the different CPU frequencies of my computer during a certain time interval. I would like to implement a supervised learning algorithm that takes a time series of CPU frequency as an input and decides, whether anything "unusual" happened during that time (unusual CPU usage etc).

**EDIT:**

My data sets look the following way, every 10 seconds the current CPU frequency is measured. I have not specified an exact number of datapoints per set, the following is just for illustration. But I am expecting around 2500 datapoints per set:

Dataset_1: {1.2, 1.2, 1.6, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4, 1.5} -> Label: "good"

Dataset_2: {1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0} -> Label: "good"

Dataset_n: {1.3, 1.2, 3.6, 3.5, 1.4, 1.5, 3.3, 3.2,
1.2} -> Label: "bad"

My understanding of a supervised ML algorithm is that i have training datasets. However, every tutorial that i have found so far always labels each value in a data set. In my case that would not be possible, as I could only tell my ML algorithm:

a) this time series data set is normal

b) in this data set something is not normal

but i wouldn't be able to label each individual value, meaning i cannot say:

1.2 -> good

1.3 -> bad

1.4 -> good

As there are many different ML algorithm, it is hard for a beginner to determine which is a good one to use. So my question is:

Which (python implemented) algorithm could i use as a start, that accepts labels for entire datasets and does not expect each value to be labeled.

I hope this question makes sense, edits are highly welcome as much as your time! thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom, could you be more specific please (update your question appropriately, so more people may be able to help you)? 1) I guess the data you are working with are sets of N dimensional vectors (f_1, f_2, ...., f_N) where f_t is the frequency of your CPU at time t and categories are {normal, abnomal}. Correct? Value of N? f_t are ints or floats? 2) You have two datasets: the first is a training set but it only contains data classified as normal, the second one is an unclassified dataset, correct? 3) Size of the two datasets (i.e., n. of data points in each one)?

Answer (score 0):

For this application I would go with KNN(K - nearest neighbors). Tech with Tim has a great tutorial on KNN, explains it well and shows the implementation.
Hope this helps

Comment: I guess that the training dataset only contains data points from one of the categories. If my guess is correct, a kNN algorithm will not work, as all the unclassified data points will be classified as of being in this unique category (no matter the distance to the training data points).

Comment: Hi @LaosLos, could you explain this a bit further? I do not understand this part "all the unclassified data points will be classified as of being in this unique category", which unclassified datapoints? in the training set?